# Safari bug with CSS rounded corner rendering

Tags: css, safari

Running Safari 5.05.

This CSS is looks fine in Chrome and Firefox, but when displayed in Safari, the border-left only spans to the beginning of the border-radius. This leaves a gap at the top/bottom.

```
.boxWithLeftBorder {
height:100px;
width:100px;
background: #ddd;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
border-radius:10px;
border-left: 20px;
border-color:#000;
border-style:solid;}
```

I've included an image below to clarify.

Given the wisdom of the crowds I'm guessing this is either well known or there is an easy workaround. I've Googled to the best of my ability and would appreciate any ideas. Thanks!!

[image: boxWithLeftBorder image]

Comment: Keep in mind that border radius is part of the CSS3 and as such, is an incomplete standard. Subsequently, browser support is bound to be a bit flaky for a while yet.

Comment: wow, that is weird... seems odd since both chrome and safari run on webkit, that one would be fine but not the other. I'm gonna say this is a bug. I have no idea as to a workaround...

Comment: FYI, here's what the spec says: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#corner-shaping I'm certain this is a WebKit bug too.

Comment: The border on the left should span from the top border all the way to the bottom border. Those gaps shouldn't be there.

Comment: Re: Webkit bug in Safari. This is what I was thinking since Chrome looks fine.

Comment: I submitted this as bug to Apple Dev Bug Reporting. If anyone feels compelled, please use better channels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using some creative [CSS pseudo elements](http://css-tricks.com/browser-support-pseudo-elements/) (`:before` or `:after`), you can achieve your effect ***and*** use minimal markup at the same time. *Note: The red border color emphasis is mine.*

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="boxWithLeftBorder">Lorem Ipsum</div>
```

CSS:

```
.boxWithLeftBorder {
    background: #ddd;
    border: 3px solid #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 0;
}

.boxWithLeftBorder:before {
    background-color: #c00;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20px;
}
```

Edit this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BYa9C/5/

Comment: Great thanks! This works well and I appreciate being able to do it without additional HTML markup. I'll be sure to vote you up once I have enough rep. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Safari 5.05 and Firefox 3.6+ should support border-radius without the -webkit- and -moz- prefix.

If you have elements inside your rounded-corner elements, the will need to have completely transparent backgrounds or to have rounded corners themselves (first and last elements inside the element in discussion)

Comment: Hi, thanks. I've considered these things. I've got -webkit/-moz for backwards compato. This is a alteration of existing code. There is no element inside this div. Image above is a direct image copy from html with only `.boxWithLeftBorder` inside the body tag.

Comment: maybe you should show us the real thing (if you can, or are allowed), to see what's wrong.

Comment: Due to my noobishness I can't post images. Here is a link though to how it should look. http://i.stack.imgur.com/LI4bS.png

Comment: it seems pretty much like a browser bug to me, but just appeared an answer here which should do the trick (the answer with most votes here)

Answer (score 0):

You'll wind up with issues attempting to do this in this fashion because of how borders are drawn -- and the vagaries across different browsers at the moment.

You can hack the functionality by adding a wrapper box:

```
.outer-box
{
  padding:2px 2px 2px 20px;
  border:none;
  -moz-border-radius:10px;
  -webkit-border-radius:10px;
  border-radius:10px;
  background:#000;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
.inner-box
{
  border:none;
  -moz-border-radius:8px;
  -webkit-border-radius:8px;
  border-radius:8px;
  background:#ddd;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="outer-box">
  <div class="inner-box"></div>
</div>
```

I leave in the -moz and -webkit prefixes because There is still a significant amount of Firefox 3.5 and Safari 4 out there.

Note that the inner box has a smaller radius.  This is necessary because the angles will change as you shrink the boxes.

Comment: Ok, this is helpful. I presume this hack will display fine in FF/Chrome so I'll try it out and report back. Thanks :)

Comment: Ah... just saw your 2nd image posting.  Would have been helpful from the start, since we were just guessing at the intended behavior.  : )

To do what you're looking for, just use a different border-radius on the interior:
border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I had been staring at it so much I presumed the text description accompanying the buggy behavior picture would be illustrative enough. Thanks for the help. :)